# Meteor fetch server-side job without collection

Tags: rest, meteor

I want to submit a request from my Meteor client to the server, that has the server make an HTTP request to a website, and then return the response to the client.

On a REST web server, I would make an HTTP `GET` from the client to the server, which would then make its own request and respond to the client.

I haven't added a REST interface to my Meteor app and don't want to add this overhead for just this one need. However, using collections to get this done is unweildy and not the right tool.

Is there any way for the Meteor client to securely ask the server to do something and get a response without using collections? I'm messing with meteor Methods such as:

```
Meteor.methods({
    '/http/get'(name, cbk) {
        cbk = cbk || function() {};
        HTTP.get('http://www.google.com', {}, (err, data) => {
            cbk(err, data);
        });
    },
});
```

However this isn't seeming to work. The call is being made on the Client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what Meteor methods are for.

[Meteor methods docs](https://guide.meteor.com/methods.html#defining-and-calling)

**Server**
First define your method on your server:

```
Meteor.methods({
    // Namespace for clarity
    'make.rest_call'(callback) {
        HTTP.get('http://www.google.com', {}, (err, data) => {
            callback(err, data);
        });
    }
});
```

OR

If you need the client to do something with the data then return a promise here ([promise docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise))

```
Meteor.methods({
    // Namespace for clarity
    'make.rest_call'(callback) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
            HTTP.get('http://www.google.com', {}, (err, data) => {
                if (err) { reject(err); }
                resolve(data);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

**Client**
Then call it from your client:

```
// Simple call (just makes the call, does nothing on the client)
Meteor.call('make.rest_call');
```

OR

```
// Promise based call
Meteor.call('make.rest_call', (error, result) => {
    if (error) { /* do something with error */ }

    // result contains your promise.
    result.then((data) => {
        // do something with returned data
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! When I try this though, the Client tries to make an HTTP request as well as the server, and gets  a CORS error. How do I make it so that just the server tries to make the HTTP request, and then have it return to the client?

Comment: I currently have this working by adding a try / catch to the HTTP request, however this seems hokey.

Comment: You can't make cross origin requests from modern web clients unless the queried origin has a special header. This is not always possible or feasible and is why we need to make this call from the server only. I have labeled exactly where each bit of code goes which should make it easier to follow.

Comment: Ohhhh so I just never define the Method on the client? I've always been defining my methods in a file loaded by both the Client and Server. I thought that was requried.

Comment: Well that explains why it was executing twice ;). It should all be downhill from here.

Comment: by default, server-only methods only exist as stubs on the client. So don't worry about defining it "twice" or anything, just define it on the server and call it. If you want to use Promises, have a look at this: https://github.com/deanius/meteor-promise

Comment: Okay. And the client will recognize it even if not defined?